# How to access a complicated instance variable in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin, and have no idea how to assign value for complicated variables.

Given I'm in a class, I need to do some validations on this `content` variable.

```
class MyClass(
    // other variables 
    val content: Content,
)
```

This `Content` object is another data class, which contains two other variables. One of them, the `contents` variable, is a list of another data class called `ContentItem`. As you can see below.

```
data class Content(
    val contentType: ContentType,
    val contents: List<ContentItem>
)

data class ContentItem(
    val locale: Locale,
    val title: String,
    val content: String
)
```

So my question is, given I'm in the `MyClass` class (first snippet of code above), how can I access that `locale` variable and assign value to it.

In Java, I can use Builder method. But in kotlin, I tried to use `content.contentType`, then I stuck here and I don't know how to access the `locale` variable

Comment: Why do you want to "assign value to it"? Aren't you doing _validation_? Why would that involve changing anything at all? Can you show exactly how you would do this in Java, so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: You cannot assign a value to it. As `content` is a `val` in `MyClass` it must be assigned in its constructor. As both `Content` and `ContentItem` are `data` classes they are immutable. Therefore the value of `locale` must _already have been assigned_.

Comment: @Sweeper I have another variable called `location` in MyClass, what I want to do is set specific `locale` for specific `location`, that's what I mean validations for `locale`. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: In addition to what @BoristheSpider said, there could be multiple, or zero, `ContentItem`s in a `Content` object, since `contents` is declared to be a _list_. So, which `ContentItem` do you want to set the `locale`? And what do you want to do if there is no `ContentItem`s?

Answer (score 1):

To start, lets understand what is `val` in kotlin (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables)

`val` is immutable and can not be reassigned, in your case it is a constructor parameter so after the class is initialized you can not set it.

Kotlin constructors can have named parameters, so it kind of act like a java builder. e.g.

```kotlin
class MyClass(
  val id: String,
  val name: String = "foo",
)

fun main() {
  // init like a builder, name will get the default value "foo"
  val myClass1 = MyClass(
    id = "foo",
  )

  // init like a builder, give name a different value
  val myClass2 = MyClass(
    id = "bar",
    name = "bar",
  )
}
```

Lets say you want to initialize it and based on content type put something in the locale:

```
val contentType = ContentType.FOO // i guess its an enum

val myClass = MyClass(
  content = Content(
    contentType = contentType,
    contents = listOf(
      ContentItem(
        locale = if (contentType == ContentType.FOO) ... else ...,
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

In case you want to reassign values in immutable data classes, you can use data classe's copy function:

```
val myClass = MyClass(...)

val newContentType = ContentType.BAR

val mutatedMyClass = myClass.copy(
  content = myClass.content.copy(
    contentType = newContentType,
  )
)
```